# Python 2.7 - Spynner - High RAM Usage Upon Page Refresh

Tags: python, python-2.7, spynner

I ran into the trouble when I made Page Refresh script.

Here's the code:

```
import spynner
browser = spynner.Browser()
```

When I type

```
browser.load("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

..a few times, the script eats very much RAM.

I tried:

```
browser = spynner.Browser()
browser.load("http://stackoverflow.com")
browser.close()
```

but it does not help, in other words, the eaten RAM was still the same.

So my question would be how I could load any page many times without getting my RAM to be eaten up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [Ghost.py](https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py)?

Comment: Thanks, Ghost.py is much more convenient.

Comment: I'll try to implement Ghost.py to my script tomorrow, since it does not eat as much RAM as spynner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using Ghost.py. Form what I've seen while using it myself, it is a resource-light, fast headless Python browser.